# Creating a new folder in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I must be missing something really obvious, but when in Nautilus, how do I create a new folder if the window is full of other folders/files?

Whenever I right click, only the context menu of a subfolder/file is given, as the window is full:

[image]

Comment: This is *known* bug in Nautilus GUI. It was not introduced in **13.04** ..

Comment: Did anyone raise a bug for this? It makes it annoying for me to use but impossible for my mother.

Comment: a bug report exists, but isn't getting much attention: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1381415

Comment: Bug is fixed as of 2018-05-05

Comment: I am from Ubuntu 20.04 era, problem is still there.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Switch back to icon view, so you can click outside the area of where the folders are. In list view, clicking anywhere will select the row you're clicking on.

Alternatively, you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new folder.

Would also be reasonable to [file a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) that it's not easy to create a new folder with right clicking in list view when screen is full, though it can be done in icon view.

Answer (score 26):

You can create a new folder by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> Or right clicking when there is a space to right click not on a folder.  You can also click on the gear icon on the top right of the window and click "New Folder".

[image]

Comment: This answer was probably valid when it was posted, but as of mid 2017, on Ubuntu 16.04, there is no gear anymore on the top-right of the windows.  CTRL-SHIFT-N still stands though.

Answer (score 23):

Now, in 18.04 (2018) there are these three horizontal lines in the top right corner. If you click on them there will be a small window and in it you will find a create new folder button. But still quite unbelievable to hide nifty things like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is not obvious. I think this could be improved.

Comment: This seems to be missing in 2023 (Ubuntu 23.04).

Answer (score 2):

As of mid 2017, with Nautilus 3.14.3 on Ubuntu 16.04, `CTRL-SHIFT-N` works, but so does going to the top menu and select `File / New Folder`.

I do believe that a button should be made available for this simple function.

Comment: Alas I don't see a top menu, or `File` entry anywhere in Ubuntu 23.04.